# Configure "Total Value Opportunities" on the campaign object

Tags: opportunity, campaign

I would like to know how are configured the fields "Total Value Opportunities" and "Total Value Won Opportunities" on the campaign object.

They sum the custom field "Marge" on the Opportunity object.

In the documentation, it says these fields are read-only and are automatically calculated but how please?

Where can I find the page where it is setted?

This is the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=campaigns_fields.htm&language=th)

Regards
Aurélien

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each Opportunity that you create, you can link to a Campaign (using the standard "Primary Campaign Source" lookup field on Opportunity). You can do this either manually, or automate this via [Campaign Influence](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=campaigns_influence_intro.htm&language=en).

The field "Total Value Opportunities" will show the sum of the "Amount" field values for all Opportunities so linked to the particular Campaign you're viewing. The field "Total Value Won Opportunities" will do the same, but will sum only those Opportunities that are in stage "Closed Won".

Comment: If you still see a mismatch be sure to check your stageName definitions on the Opportunity. Unfortunately you need to define every stage either as "open", "Closed/Lost" or "Closed/Won", so one of your stages might be treated as won, even though it's just not "lost".